Not getting the exception, scenarios details in console while running runner file as junit test. Working fine when run as cucumber feature
cucumber feature:
    Feature: feature to test login functionality

    Scenario: Check successful login with valid credentials
    Given user is on login page
    When user enters username and password
    And clicks on submit
    Then user verifies the home page

Step Definition:
    public class Login {
    
        @Given("user is on login page")
    public void user_is_on_login_page() {
        System.out.println("User is on login page");
        
    }

    @When("user enters username and password")
    public void user_enters_username_and_password() {
        System.out.println("User enters credentials");
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
        
    }

    @And("clicks on submit")
    public void clicks_on_submit() {
        System.out.println("User clicks on submit");
        
    }

    @Then("user verifies the home page")
    public void user_verifies_the_home_page() {
        System.out.println("User verifies home page");
        
    }

    }

Runner file:
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/Features" , 
                     glue={"StepDefinitions"} ,    
                     stepNotifications=true)
    public class TestRunner {

    }

While running as cucumber feature output is like this:

Scenario: Check successful login with valid credentials # src/test/resources/Features/Login.feature:5
User is on login page
Given user is on login page                           # StepDefinitions.Login.user_is_on_login_page()
User enters credentials
When user enters username and password                # StepDefinitions.Login.user_enters_username_and_password()
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:53)
at StepDefinitions.Login.user_enters_username_and_password(Login.java:21)
at ✽.user enters username and password(file:///C:/Users/Tanmoy%20Dutta/eclipse-workspace/BDDJava/src/test/resources/Features/Login.feature:7)
And clicks on submit                                  # StepDefinitions.Login.clicks_on_submit()
Then user verifies the home page                      # StepDefinitions.Login.user_verifies_the_home_page()
Failed scenarios:
file:///C:/Users/Tanmoy%20Dutta/eclipse-workspace/BDDJava/src/test/resources/Features/Login.feature:5 # Check successful login with valid credentials
1 Scenarios (1 failed)
4 Steps (1 failed, 2 skipped, 1 passed)
0m0.154s
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:87)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:53)
at StepDefinitions.Login.user_enters_username_and_password(Login.java:21)
at ✽.user enters username and password(file:///C:/Users/Tanmoy%20Dutta/eclipse-workspace/BDDJava/src/test/resources/Features/Login.feature:7)

While running as junit test, the output is like this:

User is on login page
User enters credentials

While i am running the test as cucumber feature, the console output is just fine.
But when running runner file as junit test, the console output is not same.
it is printing the Sysout but not all the details.
I am expecting the same output as and when run as cucumber feature.
Please suggest what's going wrong.
